# Is it possible to get output from a BASH script via the print command?

Tags: bash

I am just getting started with BASH scripting and have run into a problem.

I am trying to output the value of a variable and whilst I can achieve this via the `echo` command. When I try to use the `print` command I see an error.

Here is the problem when trying to use the `print` command:

```
ian@ian-VirtualBox:~$ y=$HOME
ian@ian-VirtualBox:~$ print -- $y
**Warning: unknown mime-type for "/home/ian" -- using "application/octet-stream"
Error: no "print" mailcap rules found for type "application/octet-stream"**
```

.. and here is the output using `echo`

```
ian@ian-VirtualBox:~$ echo $HOME
/home/ian
```

Is the `print` command not supported? or is there an issue with my environment?

In case of need I am using Xubuntu 12.10

**Update following responses\feedback:**

What do I expect `print` to do?

Output the value of the variable as the echo command does.

Why am I expecting this behavior?

The examples I have been referring to use print as I have in my example above. I don't get any output just the error. So I wanted to know why this error is happening.

The examples that I have to hand *are* using the Korn Shell. I appreciate that I am using the BASH shell but in my naivety I thought it should work.

Comment: What do you expect `print` to do? Try `man print` to see what `print` actually does. As kojiro's answer suggests, it's likely you want `printf`. Note that `printf -- $y` will print the value without a trailing newline.

Comment: Thanks for the overwhelming responses - let me update my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`print` is not a standard shell command. Are you thinking of `printf`?

It might serve you to get started by reading a [shell scripting guide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/).

(The [`print` command you have on your system](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/oneiric/+package/mime-support) looks like it's for printing a file, not displaying the expansion of a name.)

Comment: `print` can be a command if it's installed. On my Ubuntu system, `/usr/bin/print` is provided by the `mime-support` package.

Comment: @KeithThompson yes, that makes it an external command, not a shell command. I'll clarify my answer.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "shell command". It looks like the OP is invoking the `mime-support` version of `print`, but it's probably not what he wants.

Comment: @KeithThompson by *shell command* I mean commands specified in the specification of the [shell command language](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html)

Comment: Ok. It's also not entirely unreasonable to refer to a command executed from a shell as a "shell command". In any case, the OP didn't use that phrase.

Comment: Just a side note: In `ksh`, `print` _is_ an inbuilt.